# Can I set my priors to the get_priors outcome (brms package) in a linear mixed effect model?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, brms

I am brand new to Bayesian statistics. I want to perform a linear mixed effect model via the `brms` package in R.
To do that, I have to set priors in my model fit. I use the `get_priors` function and apply those in the model fit.

```
library(readr)
library(brms)
library(bayesplot)
pre = read_csv("C:/mixed_model1.csv")
pre$regions = as.numeric(as.factor(pre$regions))
pre.sc = data.frame(scale(pre)) #scale all predictors to center
pre.sc = na.omit(pre.sc)
(prior <- get_prior(V1 ~ water+DC+DMC+FFMC+CAPE+Pr_avg+RH+TEMP+WS+(1|regions), data = pre.sc, family = gaussian()))
M1 <- brm(V1 ~ water+DC+DMC+FFMC+CAPE+Pr_avg+RH+TEMP+WS+(1+water+DC+DMC+FFMC+CAPE+Pr_avg+RH+TEMP+WS|regions), data = pre.sc, prior = prior, family = gaussian(), warmup = 1000, iter = 6000, chains = 4, control = list(adapt_delta = 0.95))
priors <- c(prior(normal(0.01,1), class = Intercept),
            prior(normal(-0.1,1), class = b, coef = 'water'),
            prior(normal(0.03,1), class = b, coef = 'CAPE'),
            prior(normal(0.02,1), class = b, coef = 'DC'),
            prior(normal(0.05,1), class = b, coef = 'DMC'),
            prior(normal(0.06,1), class = b, coef = 'FFMC'),
            prior(normal(-0.01,1), class = b, coef = 'Pr_avg'),
            prior(normal(-0.06,1), class = b, coef = 'RH'),
            prior(normal(0.05,1), class = b, coef = 'TEMP'),
            prior(normal(-0.01,1), class = b, coef = 'WS'),
            prior(normal(0,1), class = sigma),
            prior(normal(0,1), class = sd)) #these are set based on the get_prior and the mean and standard deviation of each variable
M2 <- brm(V1 ~ water+DC+DMC+FFMC+CAPE+Pr_avg+RH+TEMP+WS+(1+water+DC+DMC+FFMC+CAPE+Pr_avg+RH+TEMP+WS|regions), data = pre.sc, prior = priors, family = gaussian(), warmup = 1000, iter = 6000, chains = 4, control = list(adapt_delta = 0.95))

posterior_summary(fit.w.prior)

# Trace plot of Linear Regression, define variables to plot via pars flag
mcmc_trace(fit.w.prior,  pars = c("b_Intercept", "b_water", "b_DC", "b_DMC", "b_FFMC", "b_CAPE", "b_Pr_avg", "b_RH", "b_TEMP", "b_WS", "sigma"), n_warmup = 500)

# ACF plot for Linear Regression, lags can be easily defined in the function
mcmc_acf(fit.w.prior, pars = c("b_Intercept", "b_water", "b_DC", "b_DMC", "b_FFMC", "b_CAPE", "b_Pr_avg", "b_RH", "b_TEMP", "b_WS", "sigma"), 
         lags = 15)

pp_check(fit.w.prior)
```

When I compare this model with one model fit from `brms` too, but without any priors via the `loo` function, I get that the model fit including priors from `get_priors` perform better.
Is it that 'simple' to use the given ```get_priors``` function for setting my priors in the model fit?

Comment: Is your question "Should I always use the default priors suggested by `get_prior` and never think about what might be reasonable priors for the problem at hand?" The answer to that question is that `get_prior` should not be a substitute for thinking and incorporating your domain knowledge into the choice of prior.

Comment: My question is then more; is running model `M2` with ` prior = get_prior` than similar to model `M1` where `prior` has not been defined via the `get_prior` function?

Comment: It's not clear what M1 and M2 are; nor do we have access to actual data. Instead I suggest that you learn how to extract information about the prior distributions (from `brms` models and model specifications) as well as how to simulate from those priors. This should help you make informed choices.

Comment: I have updated my question including `M1` and `M2`. I have used the `get_prior` to set my priors and tried setting them myself based on the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, only you as the person with domain knowledge can choose priors that make sense for the problem at hand. I'm not sure what kind of feedback you are looking for. Consider doing prior predictive simulations. This is explained for example in Section 4.4.1.3 of [Statistical Rethinking](https://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/), 2nd edition. The [Biostatistics for Biomedical Research](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/) course notes by Prof. Harrell also have a couple of sections about choosing reasonable priors. It's not easy.